# What would cause a font to render differently when files are hosted on a Ubuntu server, then when they are on a Windows server?

Tags: windows, linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, fonts

I recently moved a php / html based site from one server (windows / apache) to another (ubuntu / apache). Now the font's are rendering the common fonts differently.

I had the server admin install the ms core fonts and it is still appearing incorrectly. Internet Explorer seems to be fine, but Chrome / Firefox are not.

Could really use a new direction to work in on this one. Thanks in advance.
[image: problem]

Comment: That's not a font rendering issue; it's an issue of not-being-the-same-font... Look at the S in FiOS that's a completely different style , which is not caused by font-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the style sheets being returned by the server? Is it possible that one server is adding a style sheet that indicates a different font?

Try using some of the development tools in Chrome, IE 9 or Firefox to determine the exact font being used by the blocks of text.

Comment: Now that I look at it, the only text that is messing up is the Vegur with the @font-face. The third level header is actually Vegur as well. The arial appears to be rendering correctly. When using @font-face on a linux server do you have to reference the path differently?

Answer (score 0):

Linux servers have issues with @font-face font files being in a separate folder from the css declaration. Try moving your font files into the css folder or the root itself instead of having a separate font folder. Remember to change the file path in your css.

Comment: the browser is serving a different fallback font because it can not serve the font you declared, hence the difference. Chrome inspect element tools or others like it are essential. You should check it out.